# Large family of certain subsets of a regular cardinal

Tags: set-theory

$\kappa$ is an infinite, regular cardinal. There's not much to start from as you see.

I'm asked to prove there exists a family $\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{P}(\kappa):$

$i)\ |\mathcal{A}|=\kappa^+$

$ii)\ \forall A\in\mathcal{A}\ ,|A|=\kappa$

$iii)\ \forall A,B\in\mathcal{A}\ (A\neq B\implies\ |A\cap B|<\kappa)$

To my mind, I should come up with an inductive proof which would explicitly use the fact that $\kappa$ is regular. The only thing similar to the above that I remember from my lectures in set theory is that if $\kappa=\lambda^+$ then we can divide it into $\kappa$ disjoint stationary sets. But here I would need a lot more, $\kappa^+$ -- though, not necessarily disjoint as long as the third constraint was satisfied.

Does it have to do with Ulam's theorem? The result I stated was actually a corollary from what Ulam had proved regarding the existance of $(\lambda,\lambda^+)$ matrix of subsets of $\lambda$.

Perhaps you could give me a hint? For instance, where do I start?

(All things aside - does a set of cardinality $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is regular, have to be stationary?)

Comment: Start with $\kappa$ many disjoint subsets of $\kappa$ of size $\kappa$. By transfinite induction, all you need to show now is that given any collection $\mathcal{A}=\{A_i\mid i<\kappa\}$ of $\kappa$ many sets satisfying *ii)* and *iii)*, there is a set you can add to $\mathcal{A}$ and still maintain *ii)* and *iii)*. Do it recursively, adding at stage $\alpha<\kappa$ an element of $A_\alpha$ that is larger than $\sup\{\sup(A_\beta\cap A_\alpha)\mid\beta<\alpha\}$.

Comment: By the way, no, a set of size $\kappa$ does not need to be stationary. For instance, consider the set of all successor ordinals below $\kappa$.

Comment: But wait -- if I add an element of $A_{\alpha}$ then I do it $\kappa$ times, so my $\mathcal{A}$ doesn't change its cardinality.

Comment: Do you know the proof of the statement for $\omega$? Namely, every countable almost disjoint family of sets is not maximal?

Comment: I'm looking at it right now (even more general, for $\kappa$ regular). Which closess the question I think. But out of curiosity - do you happen to know where I could find a proof for $\omega$? I'd like to see if they differ much.

Comment: Maybe Jech or Kunen? Probably Halbeisen's book as well. It's just a proof by induction at each step you collect an element which is not in the union of all the previous sets which you've avoided thus far. Since the family is infinite the construction can proceed, and you ensure that you have only met each set on a finite number of points at most.